# Disable taps events but not scrolling on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

Is it at all feasible to ignore every taps on a `UIScrollView` but still allow it to scroll? For example, if I have a bunch of `UIButton` in the `UIScrollView`, is there a way to stop the taps (i.e. the buttons aren't tappable), but the scroll view still scrolls?

I tried turning off `userInteractionEnabled` but that just doesn't let me scroll altogether...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `userInteractionEnabled` to false to `UIScrollView` subview(s).

Comment: Hah! That's clever. Let me try that.